# Inconsistent margin around equation with geometry package setup

Tags: spacing, equations, geometry

### Problem

Following a [precedent question](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/582578/inconsistent-spacing-around-equation-environments-with-eb-garamond), I realize that my thesis spacing problems are due to different packages in different condition. This time, it seems that the geometry package—or more precisely its configuration—changes spacing around equations. If we look at the rendered image, the spacing around the first equation (which has a smaller bounding box height) is higher than the other. On the right of the image is the output with the `lua-visual-debug` package.  Note that this spacing problem is not specific to LuaLaTeX, and seems to disappear when the `geometry` setup line is removed. Any idea on what might cause the problem?

### MWE

```
\documentclass[a4paper,oneside,12pt]{book}

\renewcommand{\baselinestretch}{1.2}

\usepackage[headheight=15pt]{geometry}
\geometry{hmargin=2.5cm, tmargin=3.5cm, bmargin=3cm} % removing this line fixes (in this instance) the spacing

\let\vec\mathbf

% \usepackage{lua-visual-debug}

\begin{document}

Une dernière modification de nos coordonnées consiste à se placer dans un référentiel rigidement lié aux atomes dans le laboratoire qu'on appelle référentiel mobile. On choisit le centre de gravité $G$ du système comme origine du repère, le vecteur $\vec{S}_\lambda$ comme notre axe $z$, et le vecteur $\vec{s}_\lambda$ situé dans le plan $xz$. On utilise alors les angles hypersphériques
\begin{equation}
\sigma_\lambda = (\omega_\lambda, \eta_\lambda, \phi_{S_\lambda}, \theta_{S_\lambda}, \varphi_\lambda)
\end{equation}
avec l'angle $\eta_\lambda$ définit comme
\begin{equation}
    \eta_\lambda = \arccos \frac{\vec{s}_\lambda \cdot \vec{S}_\lambda}{s_\lambda S_\lambda}
\end{equation}
où l'angle $\varphi_\lambda$ est choisi tel que $\vec{s}_\lambda$ soit dans le plan $xz$.

\end{document}
```

[image: inconsistent spacing around small and big equation]

Comment: See https://tex.stackexchange.com/q/30909/2388 about when \abovedisplayskip and when \abovedisplayshortskip is inserted.

Comment: I see no difference with or without `geometry`. It "looks" different because without `geometry` there is only a half-filled line which makes the spacing appear greater, but if you measure the distance between baselines it is exactly the same.

Comment: @campa If you measure the difference between the line-starting words "axe", "avec" and "où" there is definitely a difference.

Comment: Sorry, in the question you mentioned the first equation, so I concentrated on that one. The answer for the second equation is given in Ulrike's link.

Comment: Ok you are right, I tested fixing the short skip. Anyone wants to write an answer, mark as duplicate or should I delete the post?